# Android Jetpack: Observing ArrayList not working

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-livedata

I want to set up a basic `ViewModel` and store an `ArrayList` that can be updated and thus observed, storing it as [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

The problem is that the ViewModel's attached Fragment cannot seem to detect changes in my ArrayList when calling `.observe` on it. Though when I debug the app, I can see that the ArrayList - called `s2` - has indeed updated.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _s1 = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val _s2 = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>()
    val s1: LiveData<String>
        get() = _s1
    val s2: LiveData<ArrayList<String>>
        get() = _s2

    init {
        _s1.value = "HELLO WORLD"
        _s2.value = arrayListOf("")
    }

    fun populateList() {
        _s2.value?.clear()
        for (i in 10 downTo 1) {
            _s2.value?.add("$i bottles")
        }
    }
}
```

and the attached Fragment:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private var message2TV: TextView? = null

    // ...

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        message2TV = view?.findViewById(R.id.message_2)

        viewModel.s1.observe(this, Observer {
            view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)?.text = it
        })

        viewModel.s2.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
                message2TV?.text = ""
                it.forEach { item -> message2TV?.append("\n$item") }
            }
        })

        message2TV?.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.populateList()
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug I also found that `viewModel.s2.observe()` is not called again, after the View is clicked (and ArrayList updated). I can get it to show the list only if I change the screen orientation.

Please, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LiveData` triggers updates when you call `setValue` or `postValue` on it, giving it a reference to the new value. It can't detect if the object it currently holds changes internally, like this example where the mutable list is being modified.

As it is now, there are no `setValue` calls in your code:

```
_s2.value?.clear() // _s2.getValue()?.clear()
for (i in 10 downTo 1) {
    _s2.value?.add("$i bottles") // _s2.getValue()?.add(...)
}
```

If you want it to call the observer, you could do something like this:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _s2 = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val s2: LiveData<List<String>>
        get() = _s2

    init {
        _s2.value = listOf("")
    }

    fun populateList() {
        _s2.value = listOf() // this is a setValue call
        for (i in 10 downTo 1) {
            // _s2.setValue(_s2.getValue?.plus("$i bottles")
            _s2.value = _s2.value?.plus("$i bottles")
        }
    }
}
```

You could also keep using an `ArrayList` if you want, modify it, and then call `setValue` again with the same value, but as you've already seen, this is more error prone:

```
_s2.value?.add("$i bottles")
_s2.value = _s2.value // _s2.setValue(_s2.getValue)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now I need to `setValue` or `postValue` in order to call the observer. Worked for me :)

Comment: But this won't work on Recyclerview as new reference will always be created on each and every update. NotifiyDataSetChanged will not trigger since the last instance was replace with a new Arraylist instance.